# Paperclip 2.3.5 to 3.3.1 causes url to differ from path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-3-upgrade

I am in the process of upgrading my rails app from 2.3 to 3.2, and I am having a problem with paperclip. My app was previously using paperclip v2.3.5 and now I am using rails 3.0.20 with paperclip v3.3.1

The problem happens when I try to upload an avatar to S3. It looks like paperclip is escaping the path before sending it to S3, but when I ask for the url of a specific style, the url uses an unescaped version of the path, and this leads to a "NoSuchKey" error from S3 (more like a 404 not found)

In my model I have

```
Paperclip.interpolates :last_modified do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.updated_at.to_i
end

:path => "folder/:id/:style.:extension?:last_modified",
:url  => ":s3_domain_url",
```

So the old version of my app was using urls from S3 like:

```
http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/123/thumbnail.png?123456789
```

But now, everytime I upload an avatar, S3 will store the url like this:

```
http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/123/thumbnail.png%3F123456789
```

and asking my model for the url of thumbnail style, will return:

```
http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/123/thumbnail.png?123456789
```

which S3 can't find.

I know it seems to be an easy to fix issue, but my main concern is that the production app has a lot of users with many pictures and updating all of their images is a delicate task, and manually escaping the question mark is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out how to fix a problem that was *similar* to this. There is a new `escape_url` option. Maybe try turning that to `false`?

```
:path => "folder/:id/:style.:extension?:last_modified",
:url  => ":s3_domain_url",
:escape_url => false
```

Comment: It should be marked as the correct answer! Thank you.